# Is manual or automated error correction more practically promising in the near term?

Tags: measurement, error-correction, experimental-realization

I'm curious if there's any consensus on this question among actual practitioners, but please feel free to close it if it's hopelessly opinion-based (since we've only taken baby steps toward the experimental demonstration of scalable QEC).

The standard presentation of quantum error correction presents "manual" error correction. In that case, the (macroscopic/classical/fully decohered) operator repeatedly measures the ancilla qubits to determine which error syndromes (if any) occurred in the data qubits to which they're coupled, and then applies to the data qubits whichever unitary operations are necessary to correct those errors. But it's also possible to "automate" the error correction by having the ancillas control controlled unitaries that correct the errors automatically (cf. Mermin's Intro to Quantum Computing pg. 106). This keeps the error-correction almost completely unitary, although not quite (because the ancillas need to be reset to the reference state for the next round of error correction, and in a closed system this reset operation requires a measurement followed by an operation contingent on the measurement result).

Is successful "manual" or "automated" error correction considered easier to achieve, based on our current capabilities? I can think of an argument for either:

1. Manual error correction requires shallower quantum circuits, and might therefore require less time to perform, thereby reducing the amount of time for errors to occur.
2. Automated error correction is "more unitary" and requires fewer measurements, i.e. fewer controlled interactions between the system and the environment. This might allow the experimental designers to keep the system better physically isolated during the computation, thereby reducing uncontrolled environmental interactions that cause errors. (On the other hand, even if this is the case, then the need to repeatedly measure the ancilla qubits might eliminate that advantage in practice.)